# Index.js.map file missing when starting an angular-cli app in iPad-simulator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ios-simulator, angular-cli

When starting an angular-cli project, version `"1.0.0-beta.22-1"` in the iPad simulator it throws an error because of a missing `index.js.map` file. I can start the app in any other browser outside of the simulator, even in `Safari`.

angular-cli does not generate any `index.js.map` file.

**Question:** Any ideas how I can solve this problem? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by updating the ipad to iOS 10.2